# Issues in downloading Facebook profile picture in my app

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap, decode, bitmapfactory

I have implemented facebook sdk in my android application and I have spent past 3hrs in downloading profile picture from facebook and yet i'm not successful in downloading it.

This is my code.

```
  try { 
                    String user = Facebuk.fb.request("me");
                    jsonObject = Util.parseJson(user);
                    String id = jsonObject.optString("id");
                    name = jsonObject.optString("name");
                    URL img_url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + id
                            + "/picture?type=large");
                    dp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    if (dp == null)
                        Log.i("", "afafaffgwgwgwg");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

i get notified from the logcat that `BitmapFactory.decodestream` returns null

There were similar posts asked in Stack Overflow and there solution didn't workout for me.. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **AQuery** library which provides callback in which u get bitmap.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I'm new to android and java. Can you show a simple snippet on how to use AQuery .

Comment: `String url = "YOUR_URL";
aqueryObj.ajax(url, Bitmap.class, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, **Bitmap bitmap**, AjaxStatus status) {

        }
});`